# Bitcoin blockchain full data

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development

Where is stored a full data set of bitcoin blockchain?

Is `../blocks/` dir contains a full data for blockchain work?

I know that `../chainstate/` and other files truly contains service information, include hashes, UTXO data set and others. But is it true that the full information already is in `../blocks/` dir?

Comment: you may want to give a bit more detail about bitcoin client (wallet), operating system, versions etc, so we can follow, what you are asking here...

Comment: I get a link to Bitcoin Forum > Local > Русский (Russian) - you will end up hoping for someone with cyrillic capabilities to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will add an answer to this post

- chainstate: Container the information about the UTXO and this is by default indexed in a level db.
- blocks: Contains all the data related to the blockchain, so you can build your own chain state with just scan this file (blkXXXX.dat) one by one